# Rotate line with fixed size by mouse

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

I'm trying to create something like cue in billiards game and need to rotate fixed size line by mouse.

I want that line which follow mouse position will fixed, for example 100 pixels.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/DAEpy/1/

I tried do this with `rotate()` function, but it rotates all canvas.

So, my line has 1 fixed end and fixed size (maybe 100 pixels), and it will follow mouse.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just determine the angle between the start point of the line and mouse position:

```
var dx = mouse.x - line.x1,
    dy = mouse.y - line.y1,
    angle = Math.atan2(dy, dx);
```

Then render the line using 100 pixel radius:

```
line.x2 = line.x1 + 100 * Math.cos(angle);
line.y2 = line.y1 + 100 * Math.sin(angle);
```

## Demo

```js
var ctx = document.querySelector("canvas").getContext("2d"),
    line = {
      x1: 150, y1: 70,
      x2: 0, y2: 0
    },
    length = 100;

window.onmousemove = function(e) {
  //get correct mouse pos
  var rect = ctx.canvas.getBoundingClientRect(),
      x = e.clientX - rect.left,
      y = e.clientY - rect.top;

  // calc line angle
  var dx = x - line.x1,
      dy = y - line.y1,
      angle = Math.atan2(dy, dx);

  //Then render the line using 100 pixel radius:
  line.x2 = line.x1 + length * Math.cos(angle);
  line.y2 = line.y1 + length * Math.sin(angle);
 
  // render
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 300, 150);
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(line.x1, line.y1);
  ctx.lineTo(line.x2, line.y2);
  ctx.stroke()
  
}
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```